# Object values are becoming null instantly

Tags: javascript

I have the following functions with two `console.log()` calls.

```
get = function(path, obj){
    for(var i = 0, path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]/), len = path.length; i < len; i++){
        if(path[i]){
            console.log(obj);
            obj = obj[path[i]];
            console.log(obj);
            if(typeof obj === 'undefined'){
                return '';
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

set = function(path, obj, dta){
    for(var i = 0, path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]/), len = path.length; i < len; i++){
        if(path[i]){
            obj = obj[path[i]];
            if(typeof obj === 'undefined'){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    obj = dta;
    return true;
};
```

I then call them like this:

```
var data = {
    user: {
        secret: null,
        accessToken: null
    },
    baseurl: 'http://api.example.com'
};

set('user', data, {/* new object data */});

get('user', data);
```

When the first `console.log()` is called, the object looks like this:

```
{
    baseurl: "http://api.example.com",
    user: {
        accessToken: "12324",
        secret: "123413421341342134"
    }
}
```

Then when the second `console.log()` is called, the `secret` and `accessToken` look like this:

```
{
    secret: null, accessToken: null
}
```

What is causing these to become null?

Comment: can you add some descriptions of the functionality?

Comment: Can you show `set()`?

Comment: Please add a JSfiddle

Comment: @PaulRoub I have added the set

Comment: `set()` doesn't actually *do* anything. It sets a local variable that is never returned. See here, the logged values are *always* `null`: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbQeQR?editors=001

Comment: @PaulRoub: That's an answer. (And a good one.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Or a "can't reproduce" close-vote reason.

Comment: So the value isn't a reference? Can I make it a reference?

Comment: @PaulRoub: Indeed, though it illustrates the whole pass-by-value thing, e.g., assigning to `obj` inside `set` has no effect at all on whatever was passed into it.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn: The **value** is a reference, to the object; the argument is not a reference to your variable containing the object. And you can't make it one, JavaScript is purely pass-by-value. If you wrote to properties on `obj`, that would mutate the object that it points to, which is different from overwriting the object reference in `obj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `set()` function does nothing. Assigning an object member to a variable, then setting that variable, doesn't affect the original object member.

You can keep track of the *parent* of the property-in-question, and use that to do your assignment:

```
set = function(path, obj, dta){
    var parent = obj;
    var selector = null;

    for(var i = 0, path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]/), len = path.length; i < len; i++){
        if(path[i]){
            parent = obj;
            selector = path[i];

            obj = obj[path[i]];

            if(typeof obj === 'undefined'){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    if (parent && selector)
    {
      parent[selector] = dta;
      return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

```js
var get = function(path, obj) {
  for (var i = 0, path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]/), len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (path[i]) {
      console.log(obj);
      obj = obj[path[i]];
      console.log(obj);
      if (typeof obj === 'undefined') {
        return '';
      }
    } // x
  }
  return obj;
};


var set = function(path, obj, dta) {
  var parent = obj;
  var selector = null;

  for (var i = 0, path = path.split(/[\[\]\.]/), len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (path[i]) {
      parent = obj;
      selector = path[i];

      obj = obj[path[i]];

      if (typeof obj === 'undefined') {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (parent && selector)
    parent[selector] = dta;

  return true;
};

var data = {
  user: {
    secret: null,
    accessToken: null
  },
  baseurl: 'http://api.example.com'
};

set('user', data, {
  secret: 1,
  accessToken: 2
});

get('user', data);
```

Comment: Thanks! I always thought that javascript did this by reference or by value depending on how the parameter is used.